# ggplot gradient map with horizontal and vertical breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm trying to do a risk matrix, with gradient colors using ggplots.

The boundaries for each color are defined by a reference book and the matrix must follow it.

I was able to create the color scheme with gradient based on the value of the pixel. However, there are also vertical and horizontal breaks, which i was not able to code.

and i want to set limits like this:
i.e,
[image]

Is it possible?

Many thanks,
Diogo

So far i have this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

colour_breaks <- c(0,4,7,10,15)
colours <- c("green","blue","yellow","orange","red")

db <- seq(from=5,to=1,by=-0.1)%*%t(seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.1))
db<- as.data.frame(db)

row.names(db) <- db[,1]
colnames(db) <- seq(from=1,to=5,by=0.1)

db$ID <- db[,1]
db <-  db[-nrow(db),] 

db_long <- db %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -ID) %>%
  mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID)) %>%
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(variable))
    
plt1 <-  ggplot(data=db_long, aes(x=as.numeric(variable), y=as.numeric(ID), fill=value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  annotate('segment', x = 3.4, xend = 3.4, y = -Inf, yend = 1.4,
           size = 0.1,
           alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1.4, alpha=0.4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=2.4, alpha=0.4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=3.5, alpha=0.4) +
  ylab("Condition") +
  xlab("Critic") +
  ggtitle("Risk Matrix") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    limits  = range(db_long$value),
    colours = colours[c(1, seq_along(colours), length(colours))],
    values  = c(0, scales::rescale(colour_breaks, from = range(db_long$value)), 1),
  ) +
  #scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="green",high="red") +
  theme_bw()

print(plt1)
```

Comment: Not sure whether I got you right. But perhaps you want `scale_fill_stepsn`?

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of `scale_fill_stepsn`. However i need to go one step further: i need to break the colors at certain XX and YY limits. For example: greens can only go until XX = 3.4, or blue colors until yy=5.4. That is the thing i cannot solve